# Failed to open Camera

Tags: android

I am developing an Android Application which currently looks fine in the emulator and on a Nexus 5 device.

However, on a brand new Samsung J5 device, I do have an issue with the camera.
Here is the output from the Logcat:

```
08-31 15:36:28.367    6551-6731/be.dsoft.debouwenconstructieapp E/CameraInstance﹕ Failed to open camera
java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
        at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:550)
        at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:390)
        at com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.OpenCameraInterface.open(OpenCameraInterface.java:83)
        at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.camera.CameraManager.open(CameraManager.java:121)
        at com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.camera.CameraInstance$3.run(CameraInstance.java:158)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Off course my permissions are set correctly because it's working on another device, but see below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

The following code gives me an issue:

```
  // Gets the view in the scanner will be showed.
   barcodeScannerView = (CompoundBarcodeView)findViewById(R.id.barcode_scanner_view);
   // Start capturing a set a callback to catch the results.
   capture = new CaptureManager(this, barcodeScannerView);
   capture.initializeFromIntent(getIntent(), savedInstanceState);
   barcodeScannerView.decodeSingle(callback);
```

**Note:** On my Nexus 5 device, I'm running an Android 6 built, and there I had the same problem.
After hours of searching, I finally found out that since Android 6, you can control permissions per app (and there, the camera was disabled). After enabling this, it was working fine on my device.

Now, the Samsung device runs an Android 5 built where the app permissions cannot be changed, however, I do see the error mentioned above.

Anoyone knows what's wrong?

Kind regards

Comment: Try opening the camera using Intent like here: https://achorniy.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/howto-launch-android-camera-using-intents/

Comment: Thx but I don't need to open the Camera, but I need the ZXING library. Also, this does not explain why it does work on some devices while it doesn't on other devices.

Comment: Restart your device and try again. Maybe another app was using the camera and didnt released it.

Comment: I've already done that for numerous times. However, it doesn't work.